# Running an if statement in shell script as a single line with docker -c option

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile, sh

I need to run below code as a single line in docker run -it image_name -c \bin\bash --script with --script below
(dir and dockerImageName being parameters)

```
'''cd ''' + dir+ ''' \
&& if make image ''' + dockerImageName''' 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "No rule to make target"; then
exit 1
fi'''
```

How can this be run as a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract all of this logic into your higher-level application.  If you can't do this, write a standard shell script and `COPY` it into your image.

The triple quotes look like Python syntax.  You can break this up into three parts:

1. The `cd $dir` part specifies the working directory for the subprocess;
2. `make ...` is an actual command to run;
3. You're inspecting its output for some condition.

In Python, you can call [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) with an array of arguments and specify these various things at the application level.  The array of arguments isn't reinterpreted by a shell and so protects you from this particular security issue.  You might run:

```python
completed = subprocess.run(['make', 'image', dockerImageName],
                           cwd=dir,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
if 'No rule to make target' in completed.stdout:
  ...
```

If you need to do this as a shell script, doing it as a proper shell script and making sure to quote your arguments again protects you.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd "$1"
if make image "$2" 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "No rule to make target"; then
  exit 1
fi
```

You should never construct a command line by combining strings in the way you've shown.  This makes you vulnerable to a *shell injection attack*.  Especially if an attacker knows that the user has permissions to run `docker` commands, they can set

```
dir = '.; docker run --rm -v /:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow'
```

and get a file of encrypted passwords they can crack at their leisure.  Pretty much anything else is possible once the attacker uses this technique to get unlimited root-level read/write access to the host filesystem.

Comment: I see little reason to replace a single `&&` with `set -e` to ensure the following `if` statement only runs if the `cd` succeeds.